# Compound image background CSS showing continuity

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to show a **message text bubble** with an image in background, while having a **bottom-right arrow** that shows **continuity**. You will see in the image below that the arrow doesn't continue the image from the bubble. It is important to mention that the bottom right arrow is made out of a clipping mask with the same background. How is it possible to make the image of the bottom arrow have **sense of continuity** with the background image of the bubble?

[image]

You can see below the HTML used, as well as the CSS involved for each one.

```css
div {
      display: block;
    }
    .container {
      position: relative;
    }
    .first {
      background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/fNsIPdT.png");
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      display: block;
    }

    .first.container.boxBubble {
      width: 250px;
      height: 140px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-left: 110px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/xH6YWZ3.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .tri-right-im.btm-left-in-im:after{
      content: ' ';
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      left: 180px;
      right: auto;
      top: auto;
      bottom: -30px;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 91% 0, 100% 100%);
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 91% 0, 100% 100%);
      background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/xH6YWZ3.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .talk-bubble {
      margin: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: auto;
      background-color: lightyellow;
    }
    
    .round{
      border-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius: 20px;

    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container first">
  <div class="first container boxBubble tri-right-im btm-left-in-im"></div>
  <div class="talk-bubble tri-right round btm-left-in"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why -1? If you it, just let me know what's wrong and I will try to improve the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="clip"></div>
      <div id="boxBubble"></div>      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/dwo8rS/1.png") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#clip {
  background:url("https://image.ibb.co/eJbWd7/IMG_20170611_WA0025.jpg") no-repeat top center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 20% 0, 80% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 60%, 80% 80%, 80% 100%, 60% 80%, 20% 80%, 0 60%, 0 20%);
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 5;
}
#boxBubble {
  background:url("https://image.ibb.co/eJbWd7/IMG_20170611_WA0025.jpg") no-repeat top center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  border-radius: 20px;  
  width: 250px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -200px auto 0;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

This is one way you could do it. I hope this helps you! https://jsfiddle.net/keganv/3j5c4gg0/116/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. Clipping seems to be the right answer. :) +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `background-attachment:fixed;` to both element so they will have the same origin and thus you will have the continuity of the background:

```css
div {
      display: block;
    }
    .container {
      position: relative;
    }
    .first {
      background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/fNsIPdT.png");
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      display: block;
    }

    .first.container.boxBubble {
      width: 250px;
      height: 140px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-left: 110px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/xH6YWZ3.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment:fixed;
      background-position:center;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .tri-right-im.btm-left-in-im:after{
      content: ' ';
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      left: 180px;
      right: auto;
      top: auto;
      bottom: -30px;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 91% 0, 100% 100%);
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 91% 0, 100% 100%);
      background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/xH6YWZ3.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position:center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment:fixed;
    }

    .talk-bubble {
      margin: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: auto;
      background-color: lightyellow;
    }
    
    .round{
      border-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius: 20px;

    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container first">
  <div class="first container boxBubble tri-right-im btm-left-in-im"></div>
  <div class="talk-bubble tri-right round btm-left-in"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. However, it does not mimic the bubble shape I gave before.

Comment: @juanba1984 i updated with another answer much easier ;) you can have a look if stil interested

Comment: Hi Temani, nice answer, despite it's not exactly what I want. I love the moving effect inside the bubble. Thank you!